# sending data through ajax to CI controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to ajax and CI  .I want to send data and image through ajax . In my view i have 3 input fields and one image upload button .

```
var val1 = $("#val1"+id).val();
var val2 = $("#val2").val();
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page/save_data",
            data: "{ val1 :'"+val1+"',val2:'"+val2+"}",
            success: function(msg) {

                    alert(msg);
            }
    });
```

and in controller when i try this it shows me nothing

```
function save_data()
{
    $val = $this->input->post('val1');
    echo $val1;


}
```

In console it gives me nothing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url: "page/save_data",
            data: { "val1 ":val1,"val2": val2},
            success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Please check that the URL you are hitting and verify that its fine or not?

Comment: @user1224233 : Welcome always

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax URL must be refer to your method name;

```
...
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page/save_data", //change this to your method;
 ...
```

should be like:

```
  ...
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page/save_iudata",//or whatever your method's name;
  ...
```

**EDIT:**

try this way:

```
function save_data(){
  $val1 = $_REQUEST['val1'];
  echo $val1;
}
```

Comment: you got @Arvind answer, dont quote the data object;

Answer (score -1):

Hello to send data via ajax is easy:

```
        var data = {
            val1: $('#val1').val(),
            val2: $('#val2').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url().'page/save_data'; ?>",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            async : false,
            data: data,

            success: function(msg){
                ...
            }
        });
        return false;
```

But to send an image you have to do some research...
here is a good [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/)